# How general fibers determine a special fiber?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, deformation-theory

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a (flat and projective) family of hypersurfaces over a variety $Y$, and let $B\subset Y$ be a closed subset with ${\rm codim_Y(B)}\geq 2$. I would like to know that:

> if we know (the isomorphism class of) every fiber in $Y\backslash B$, is it true that we also know the (isomorphism class of) fiber in $B$?

If we drop out the condition of codimention $2$, then we have many counter-examples, say $x^2-y^2=t$ defines a family over $t\in \mathbb A^1$, and all fibers except at $0$ are isomorphic. But this phenomenon does not occur when codimension of $B$ is at least $2$.

Comment: Blowing up a point in $Y$ and then fibering with the map $X \to Y$ gives a counter-example, no?

Comment: @RghtHndSd I did not understand. Could you say more in detail? If you pull it back to the blow-up, it will decrease the codimension of "$B$", so I didn't see how this gives a counter-example.

Comment: I am considering the map $\tilde{X} \to X \to Y$. It is not clear to me that $\tilde{X}$ is a family of hypersurfaces.

Comment: Ah whoops, I got confused. Of course this map isn't flat.

Comment: When you say a "family of hypersurfaces", what do you mean?

Comment: @KReiser I mean every fiber is isomorphic to a hypersurface in $\mathbb P^n$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say `if we $ know$  the isomorphism class ...' in your question?

Comment: @Mohan Say, if we have two families over $Y$, and they are fiberwise isomorphic over all closed point in $Y\backslash B$, can we expect they are pointwise isomorphic over any closed point? Sorry for not made myself clear.